# Google custom search (or alternative) in XHML

Tags: javascript, xhtml, jsapi

Google's JavaScript API makes use of the function `document.write`, thus is not usable in XHTML.

Do you know a workaround how to get the custom search working in XHTML? Or is there a working alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually serving your XHTML as XML (`application/xhtml+xml`)? If not, you don't have to worry about it, yet. `document.write` will still work in `text/html` mode though it is certainly poor practice in general.

If you really are serving native XHTML... well, I suspect you may get more problems than just `document.write`, as there are a fair few things that can trip scripting up when it's not expecting to be run in XHTML. But you can hack it the problem by sabotaging `document.write`.

The simplest method would be something like:

```
document.write= function(s) {
   document.getElementById('placetoputwrittenstuff').innerHTML= s;
};
```

however you would need more messing around if it tried to write `<script>` tags (since setting them through `innerHTML` doesn't execute them; you would have to pick them out with `getElementsByTagName` and run each one manually), or partial bits of elements across different calls to `write` (in which case you'd have to collect strings and glue them together when it's finished).